# cURL in laravel seeder

Tags: php, laravel, curl

i want to insert some api data to my database using seeder laravel. I got error that my response is null. do i make mistake in my code ?

when i code in my pc, it works. But i change into my laptop, and i got this error.

> foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given

```
use App\Models\Kategori;

class KategoriSeeder extends Seeder
{
 
    public function run()
    {
        $url = "xxx";
        $data = [
            'username' => 'xxx',
            'password' => 'xxx'
        ];

        $curl = curl_init($url);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  json_encode($data));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ]);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        foreach (json_decode($response)->data as $value) {
            $data = [
                'nama_kategori' => $value->kategori
            ];
            \App\Models\Kategori::create($data);
        }

        curl_close($curl);
    }
}
```

thank you for your time

Comment: The error message does NOT mean that $response is null, but that it couldn't be json_decoded (or doesn't have the property data). I suggest you check the value of $response before the foreach and let us know what it is.

Comment: ah sorry, my mistake. the end point deleted by my friend so its only blank. sorry to bother you, my code is fine, it work if there's data init. do i have to delete my question or let people see my code for reference ?